# how to prevent overfitting/underfitting while using EfficientNet

Tags: python, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, overfitting-underfitting, efficientnet

i'm new in python
so for my college final project, i use EfficientNet for the ripeness palm oil into 4 classification.
i've total 5852 train data (1463 each) , and 132 test data (33 each).
i used code from the internet.
but the result is far from good.
i already add layers.dropout to prevent / avoid underfitting.
and i also use imagenet to do the transfer learning.
is there any solution to improve the result?

Edit:
i already change my code from conv_base.trainable = False to conv_base.trainable = True. But i think the result still not good

here's my full code: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1OeiSA23xmF5ceq19aqc1l20mlT3Uxocs/view?usp=sharing

and here's my result

[image: model accuracy]

[image: model loss]

Comment: Your code looks good to me. I think you just need to do more experiments. For now, I would suggest you try to overfit your training data and then regularize. Also, train the `conv_base` as well.

Comment: is there any clue how to do that sir?

Comment: Chnage this line `conv_base.trainable = False` to `conv_base.trainable = True`. Also, dropout prevent Overfitting and not underfitting.

Comment: i'll try that. But, can you help me on which code to dropout the prevent overfitting and not underfitting?

Comment: i try to train my model. but another model appeared, it said "This is probably because cuDNN failed to initialize, so try looking to see if a warning log message was printed above." i already add code below to limit the memory growth. But the same error still appeared. is there any clue how to solve this?
physical_devices = tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')
tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(physical_devices[0], True)

Answer (score 0):

To my opinion 5852 samples for training Efficientnet is far from enough. You also don't have enough data for validation. I train Efficientnet on more than million samples and still it tends to overfit. My advice to you is to try a simpler CNN architecture (you can start with simple LeNet and try to add layers). If you prefer the transfer learning method try to work with BiT model (https://ai.googleblog.com/2020/05/open-sourcing-bit-exploring-large-scale.html) it will give you better results.